# Function works with 'enter', but not 'button click' (Although, I only added event to button, not to keypress)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm building a 'To Do' App Project to improve my JS, but there is an interesting problem. I added an event to the button, when I press the button the value from the input will be added to ul as li. Everything works perfect with enter key. Altough, I didn't add a keypress event, I only added button click. When I click button, it shows the error "Nothing to do?", which is the second 'else if'. Thanks in advance for your help.

```js
var button = document.getElementById('btn');
var input = document.getElementById('input');
var list = document.getElementById('list');

button.addEventListener('click', (x) => {
  if (input.value != '' & checklis()) {
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    li.classList.add('todo');
    li.innerHTML = `<i class="fas fa-circle"></i> ${input.value} <i class="fas fa-minus"></i>`;
    list.appendChild(li);
    input.value = '';
    error.textContent = '';
  } else if (input.value == '') {
    error.textContent = 'Nothing to do?'
    input.value = '';
    errorVanish();
  } else if (!checklis()) {
    input.value = '';
    error.textContent = 'Too many things to do.'
    errorVanish();
  }
  x.preventDefault();
})


function checklis() {
  const lis = document.querySelectorAll('.todo');
  if (lis.length < 9) {
    return true
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p class="error"></p>
  <header class="header">
    <h2>TASK BOX</h2>
    <p>Let's plan the day</p>
  </header>


  <div class="main_content">

    <form action="">

      <input onblur="this.value = ''" autocomplete="off" id="input" type="text" placeholder="I plan to..." onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder='I plan to...'">
      <button class="submit" id="btn"> ADD </button>
    </form>
    <ul class="list_wrapper" id="list">

    </ul>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is `input`? That variable does not seemed to be defined anywhere. Also, please show the relevant HTML.

Comment: @kmoser I updated the code with HTML. :) OH... the problem is onblur function... THANK YOUUUU!

Comment: I submitted an edit that is pending approval. However, there is no clue as to what "error" is. I bound everything else each to its element.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem was 'onblur' function in HTML. :D